# Does she/he should leave noble/Good works or stop praying God because there is no output in doing noble/good works and praying the God?

Tags: karma, prayer

Sometimes when you prayed something to God, like please make my life successful, but its doesn't happen even after praying for long time.

My question is that does she/he should leave noble/Good works or stop praying to God because there is no output/result seen in doing noble/good works and praying to God ?

Any  Guidance ?

Comment: let's say you are a parent. and your small child < 5 years asks you for something like fruit, you will immediately give to him in his hand. suppose the child has grown up now 10 years, if he asks for fruit, you will say 'it's on the table, you can go take it'. when the child is still older 15, if he asks for fruit, you will say 'here is rs.10, you can go buy in store'. when he is 20, if he asks for fruit, you will say 'here is a job at this company, you can join, do work, earn money, then buy fruit'. if the boy is now 30, and he asks you for fruit, you will say 'why are you still asking me'

Comment: same way God. when you ask for success, depending on your skill level, he won't directly give you success without working, he gives opportunity so that you get the satisfaction of earning something by yourself. if god gives you everything, tomorrow you will complain to same God 'why you don't let me do any work by myself, i am getting everything for free so none respects me'

Comment: Since you are asking for guidance, one cent from me. - Don't be dependent on anyone or anything. Be your own light. I am not asking you to polish your 'ego' But to slowly get rid of all assumptions and deal with the facts directly. Praying to 'GOD' for asking something has so many uncertainty involved like karma, etc... We don't have time to think on all these, so be your own light... Try to be with 'failure', learn to be venerable & failure. After all, success is a word invented by the society which is greedy and acquisitive. Be with whatever you get/have... 1/2

Comment: Gradually reduce your daily consumption & involve in making money without any desire while being venerable to any situation life gives but don't depend on any guru or god whatever these terms mean. This kind of lifestyle would be more factual and rational bereft of assumptions and uncertainty. 2/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

God Himself says in Gita(chapter 3, sloka 30):

> Devoid of the fever of the soul, engage in battle by dedicating all actions to Me, with (your) mind intent on the Self, and becoming free from expectations and egoism. (Translation by Swami Gambhirananda)

So we have to pray and put our best efforts simultaneously, if we can keep faith in God. So many saints realized get and got relieved of their pains and sufferings.

An atheist is free to think to do in other way.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are asking wrong things from God, only gold, worldly luxuries or fame, that is why God does not listen to your prayers

[Ramakrishna Paramhans used to say](https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/ramakrishna_211755):

> Pray to God that your attachment to such transitory things as wealth,
> name, and creature comforts may become less and less every day.
>
> **Can you weep for Him with intense longing of heart? Men shed a jugful
> of tears for the sake of their children, for their wives, or for
> money. But who weeps for God?**

[Swami Vivekananda prayer to Kali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swami_Vivekananda%27s_prayer_to_Kali_at_Dakshineswar)

> **One day Narendra requested Ramakrishna to pray to goddess Kali, the
> Divine Mother, for some financial welfare, which was the immediate
> need of his family. Ramakrishna listened to his request and told him
> that day was a Tuesday, an "auspicious day", asked him to go to the
> temple in the evening and pray it himself**[9][10] Ramarkishna also told
> Narendra about the mother goddess: She is Knowledge Absolute, the
> Inscrutable Power of Brahman and by Her mere will She has given birth
> to this world. Everything is in Her power to give.” **Narendra then
> believed the words of his master and decided to approach mother Kali
> and pray to her to rescue him of his financial problems.
>
> **First attempt to pray for financial welfare**
>
> Following the suggestion, at 9 o'clock in the evening,[10] Narendra
> prepared himself to go to the temple. As he entered the temple and
> looked at the image of Kali, he was overawed with a great feeling of
> devotion and love.[11] He went to the temple of Kali and stood in
> front of the idol, bowed to goddess Kali in an "ecstasy of joy" and
> started repeating her name. Standing before the Divine Mother he felt
> she was "living and conscious, full of divine love and beauty". **He
> prayed to the goddess for divine knowledge and devotion, and for her
> eternal divine visions but forgot to pray for financial welfare for
> which he had come.**[9][9][11]
>
> **Second attempt to pray for financial  welfare**
>
> When Narendra came to Ramakrishna, who was sitting outside the temple,
> Ramakrishna asked him, "Did you pray for your family wants?". Narendra
> was puzzled and confessed that he had forgotten to do so. Upon knowing
> this, Ramakrishna asked him to go to the temple and pray for the
> second time.[9]
>
> In accordance with Ramakrishna's suggestion, Narendra went to the Kali
> temple once again. Like the last time, he stood before the idol of
> goddess Kali bowed to her and started praying. He prayed— "Give me
> discrimination and divine knowledge. Grant me mother your unhindered
> vision", but, once again he forgot to pray for his family wants.[9]
> Then Ramakrishna admonished him saying “how thoughtless! Couldn’t you
> restrain yourself enough to say those few words?[11] Third attempt to
> pray for financial welfare
>
> Narendra came back to Ramakrishna, who once again asked him if he had
> prayed for financial support that time. **Once again, Narendra answered
> in negative and confessed that he had forgotten.** Ramakrishna asked him
> to attempt for the third time to pray for his family's immediate
> need.[12]
>
> Narendra went to Kali temple for the third time. He tried to pray for
> what he was suggested, but **started feeling ashamed of himself for
> attempting to pray worldly and material things.** So he returned to
> Ramakrishna without praying for any kind of financial welfare.
> Ramakrishna was pleased to learn that his disciple's spiritual
> inclination and did a forecast that Narendra's family would never face
> lack of essentials of living like food and clothes.[12][13] Finally
> Narendra in his own words said " I Had To Accept Her At Last!". It was
> the end of his six years of "hate of Kali! And all Her ways![11]
>
> Following this eventful revelation of goddess Kali, he would say, "I
> can not but believe that there is somewhere a great Power that thinks
> of Herself as feminine called Kali and Mother".[11]

Comment: Great matter . But kindly try to answer to the point. God Himself says in Gita that whoever worships Him for even material gains are fortunate.

Comment: @ParthaBanerjee Dharma(religion), Artha(money), Kama(luxuries) and final goal is Moksha(Liberation)/Sannyas.